# Node.js, how to make sure that client got a data from server without 'confirming' request from client

Tags: node.js, http

My HTTP server needs to make sure that HTTP responses are delivered to the client.

*I feel (and I will implement it so) that the most correctly way is to send the "I received the data" request from the client.*

But I have a bit academic question:

Has the server some **other** means to detect whether the response delivered to the client or not (say due to the client's computer was evaporated by a direct hit of an H-bomb during data transmission)?

According to the [node.js http documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish):

> **Class: http.ServerResponse**
>
> ...
>
> **Event: 'finish'**
>
> Emitted when the response has been sent. More specifically, this event
> is emitted when the last segment of the response headers and body have
> been handed off to the operating system for transmission over the
> network. It does not imply that the client has received anything yet.
>
> After this event, no more events will be emitted on the response
> object.

Also I did not find nothing better in the 'net' module documentation.

So it seems I can only know that my data is in the kernel buffer for transmisstion over the network.

**Can I detect some errors at this transmission by Node.js means?**

**Can I detect some errors at this transmission by some easy-to-implement non-Node.js means?**

Any links and thoughts that this is not an HTTP way or even not a TCP way are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about TCP is that the receiver must acknowledge the fact that it receives every single bit of data. If that's not the case, sender keeps sending the pieces of data that receiver has not yet acknowledged to receive.

I checked out the Net module and I saw this interesting piece:

```
Event: 'end'
#
Added in: v0.1.90

Emitted when the other end of the socket sends a FIN packet.
```

I have no implementation idea for this but still, this might be useful for your case.

Comment: Indeed, I also saw this 'FIN' mention in Net documentation, but due to "After this event, no more events will be emitted on the response object" string in HTTP doc, I just forgot it. Interesting that 'http.IncomingMessage' contains 'socket' property, which 'end' event could be subscribed, I think. Interesting, why http.ServerResponse object does not contain a 'socket' property. Anyway thanks, your post is useful.